# How do you permanently activate all AppArmor profiles?

Tags: apparmor

I want all the AppArmor profiles activated wherever applicable permanently, how can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To permanently put all profiles into *enforce* mode:

```
sudo aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/*
```

To permanently put all profiles into *complain* mode:

```
sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/*
```

To verify the current status of apparmor:

```
sudo aa-status
```

*complain* mode will log violations against the application profiles, whereas *enforce* mode will strictly enforce the application profiles.

Comment: By the way, would you happen to know what each and every AppArmor profile restricts and allows?

Comment: @Oxwivi: eheh, big question :) Take a look at `man apparmor.d` with the `/etc/apparmor.d/*` files opened. `apparmor` can enforce many limits on syscalls, file permissions, network stack access, etc. It is a security model for processes instead of users.

Comment: Yes, well, I don't know how to interpret it. I asked a seperate question for that specifically about Firefox's AppArmor.